# How to connect WooCommerce website to react-native?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, react-native, woocommerce, ecmascript-6

I am really confused on how does it works. Assuming that I have already my e-commerce built by WooCommerce. How can I integrate it in react-native? And how does it work? It wil be displayed on a web view?

Comment: My recommendation is to encapsulate the back end as an entirely different system to the front end, simply have your back-end act as an API? It makes it easier to manage the two different applications as separate systems in my opinion. Also, could you show what you have tried? Sorry to bombard you with questions, but why are you using react-native specifically?

Comment: for faster development? And my e-commerce app has an interactive map like uber does. And react-native is capable to do that.

Comment: Faster development, that's up for debate. No framework speeds up development time to so speak, I mean using these tools to produce hybrid web apps, yes, that's a much quicker route than developing native apps. But I was wondering more why react-native over something like PhoneGap? The end result is basically the same, it's more curiosity than anything else.

Comment: I already tried ionic which uses cordova/phonegap. It is very slow compared to react-native. React native does not uses web-view while ionic uses webview to wrap the app.

Comment: Fair enough, can't argue with that, I've personally not tested that out, so I'll take your word for it. But as I've said, could you demonstrate what you've tried so far? Any code to show? Etc.

Comment: Not yet. I just want to know how to do it :D hhha

Comment: Well... Usually you have your API, like I said, then make AJAX requests from the front end, then depending on app state you render the relevant data.... In this case the URL would be a big thing for app state... I mean usually it's an easier approach.... I'll cook up a demo if you like? - Of the front end I mean...

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I will be glad :) Please <3

Comment: Okay, because I'm busy, I'm just gonna provide basic pseudo code.... I'm currently working on my own framework project, something that enforces hard MVC into the front end, but doesn't require any compiling/transpiling, and most of all, it's gonna be lightweight! ... Anyway, here's a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/akhusxv0/).

Comment: FYI. You could always use routes to point to other JS files, etc... I mean that's the beauty of simplicity, it offers flexibility...